# In what ways are users affected when they don't follow up on Area 51 commitments?

Tags: support, area-51, penalty

When committing to an Area 51 site one has to promise to participate on the site, by posting at least ten questions and/or answers.

Obviously, this is good, since a "commit" wouldn't really mean much if it didn't come with such a promise.

Now, I'm obviously not planning to *do* this, but I'm curious: What effects are imposed on users who commit to Area 51 sites without following up on their participation pledges (commitments)? Are they prevented from committing to more sites, etc?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For starters, you'll get a nag email early on in the private beta stating you promised to participate on the site and aren't doing so. Not really a disincentive, but it does exist.

Past that, the only sanction on their account is they're eating up one of their three commitments (you can only commit to up to three proposals at a time). That commitment will continue to be used until the site leaves public beta or six months have passed since the beta started, whichever comes first (the former is pretty rare within six months). If a user did this three times, then yes, they'd be unable to commit to further proposals until some length of time has passed, or they decided to go participate on one of those three sites.

Comment: Oh, whereas if you followed up on your promise, you'd free up your new commit instantly?

Comment: Yes, you can free up that commitment within a few days of private beta and use it again, actually.

Comment: Cool, that explains it.